# I have difficulty in this chain rule. Can anyone explain this to me in simple words??

Tags: partial-derivative, mathematical-physics, chain-rule

I have difficulty in understanding the chain rule given in the picture. The derivative with $x$ do not have $\lambda$, while $y$ term have. Why is it so???
[image]

Comment: Note that there are $\lambda_i$ coefficients in front of the $y$ terms, but not the $x$ terms, so there is no symmetry reason why $\partial/\partial y$ has $\lambda_i$ coefficients, but $\partial/\partial x$ doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the chain rule,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} + \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} \\&= \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta},
\end{align}
$$
since $\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x} = 1$. The same reasoning works for $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

---

Edit: for the other chain rule,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} & = \frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} + \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} \\&= \lambda_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} + \lambda_2\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: If one lembda is with x then what would be the answer?

Comment: What do you mean by one $\lambda$ is with $x$?

Comment: What I want to say is that for both zeta and eta x do not have lembda as a coefficient and therefore the partial derivatives are similar. But what if one x (let say the zeta x) have lembda and the other (x in the eta equation) don't have lembda. What would he the chain rule then??

Comment: Say you had $\zeta = \tau_1 x + \lambda_1 y$ and $\eta = \tau_2 x + \lambda_2 y$, then then $\partial/\partial x = \tau_1 \partial /\partial \zeta + \tau_2 \partial/\partial \eta$ and the second chain rule gives the same result.

Comment: Now I understand it better.